# Docker: PostgreSQL Django FATAL: password authentication failed for user "django"

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to connect Django to the PostgreSQL server but still didn't manage to see what's the problem.

The docker container seems up and running correctly, but in Django, I get this error:

[image]

Pgdb throws me this error:

```
pgdb      | 2021-06-09 23:49:00.871 UTC [35] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "django"
pgdb      | 2021-06-09 23:49:00.871 UTC [35] DETAIL:  Role "django" does not exist.
pgdb      |     Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      DB_NAME: django
      DB_USER: django
      DB_HOST: pgdb
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_PASSWORD: django
      CELERY_BROKER: redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
      - redis
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A conf worker -l INFO
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis
  pgdb:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: django
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: django
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Django settings includes:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
    },
}
```

What's the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Wrote an article on how to do this setup neatly. https://python.plainenglish.io/django-start-building-an-api-in-8-minutes-part-1-6e901dcf8fcd